# Перевести скрипти из bash в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

Нужна ваша помощь - переделать скрипт с bash на python3.
Желательно без использования shell=True(пишут что не безопасно).
Баш скрипт в кроне раз в минуту проверяет состояние ipsec и если соединение упало - поднимает.

```
#!/bin/bash
L=`ipsec status | grep NewMyyvpn |  awk '{ print $1 }' |   tr '\n' ' ' | cut -c 1-9`
if [ -n "$L" ]; then
exit 0
else
/usr/sbin/ipsec up NewMyyvpn
fi
```

Буду очень благадарен.

Comment: Начните с поиска соответствующих библиотек., конкретно в этом случае надо какую-либо интеграцию с IPsec.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Спасибо за помощь. Получилось не красиво, но нужно же с чего-то начинать.

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output("ipsec status | grep NewMyyvpn |  awk '{ print $1 }' |   tr '\n' ' ' | cut -c 1-9", shell=True).decode("utf-8")
if not output:
#    print("Bad :-(")
    subprocess.Popen('ipsec up NewMyyvpn', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
else:
#    print("This is fine :-)")
    exit(0)
```

Возможно кому-то когда-то понадобится.

Comment: Это не питон, так писать нельзя. Ваш код должен быть в вопросе, а не в ответе.